# Why does the SQL 'select 1 from dual where 0=null;' pass in the oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I type the following SQL in the ORACLE and it passed:

```sql
select 1 from dual where 0=null;
```

Why did the SQL pass and it seems strange without compilation error. Moreover , if the null is a varchar2 column in the table, it will also pass.

```sql
create table test
(
  a varchar2(100),
  b varchar2(100)
)

insert into test(a,b) VALUES (null, 'abc');
commit;

select * from test where a=0
```

**Update:**

Because the column 'a' is the varchar2 type and 0 is a number type, if the a doesn't contain null, it will report the error.

```sql
create table test
(
  a varchar2(100),
  b varchar2(100)
)

insert into test(a,b) VALUES ('abc', 'abc');
commit;


select * from test where a=0

--ORA-01722 "invalid number"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are your expectations about that query?

Comment: What do you mean "pass"?  There is nothing *syntactically* wrong with `0 = null`.  It simply never evaluates to true.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is unexpected here?

Comment: How is this different to `where 'foo' = 'bar'`?

Comment: @Bohemian: it appears that OP is confused by the difference between a compilation error, a runtime error, and a statement which compiles and executes successfully but which does not return anything. Please reopen.

Answer (score 4):

It passes because [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065706) is correct. It contains all mandatory elements so it can be parsed. Then it is executed. Please see how statements are [processed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL175)
It not returns any result because where condition is not true.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `NULL` is a value, like any other. An (in)equality check will fail without using `is`, but the syntax is still valid.

Instead of directly writing `NULL` let's assume you're passing in a variable `:1` and re-write your query like that:

```
select 1 from dual where 0 = :1
```

In this case, the value of `:1` might be anything, the determination of this is made by the calling code and the SELECT statement that you've written doesn't know what value the calling code will pass in.

It is therefore impossible for Oracle to say that this statement is invalid, even though it could be represented exactly as you have written:

```
select 1 from dual where 0 = null
```

because it might also be:

```
select 1 from dual where 0 = 0
```